# Why a dockerized script have a different behaviour when I docker run or I docker execute it?

Tags: python, docker, websocket, sh

I'm using a python script for send websocket notification,
as suggested [here](https://websocket-client.readthedocs.io/en/latest/getting_started.html).

The script is `_wsdump.py` and I have a script `script.sh` that is:

```
#!/bin/sh

set -o allexport
. /root/.env set

env

python3 /utils/_wsdump.py "wss://mywebsocketserver:3000/message" -t "message" &
```

If I try to dockerizing this script with this `Dockerfile`:

```
FROM python:3.8-slim-buster

RUN set -xe \
    pip install --upgrade pip wheel && \
    pip3 install websocket-client

ENV TZ="Europe/Rome"

ADD utils/_wsdump.py /utils/_wsdump.py
ADD .env /root/.env
ADD script.sh /

ENTRYPOINT ["./script.sh"]
CMD []
```

I have a strange behaviour:

- if I execute `docker run -it --entrypoint=/bin/bash mycontainer` and after that I call the `script.sh` everything works fine and I receive the notification.
- if I run `mycontainer` with `docker run mycontainer` I see no errors but the notification doesn't arrive.

What could be the cause?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your script doesn't launch a long-running process; it tries to start something in the background and then completes.  Since the script completes, and it's the container's `ENTRYPOINT`, the container exits as well.

The easy fix is to remove the `&` from the end of the last line of the script to cause the Python process to run in the foreground, and the container will stay alive until the process completes.

---

There's a more general pattern of an entrypoint wrapper script that I'd recommend adopting here.  If you look at your script, it does two things: (1) set up the environment, then (2) run the actual main container command.  I'd suggest using the Docker `CMD` for that actual command

```bash
# end of Dockerfile
ENTRYPOINT ["./script.sh"]
CMD python3 /utils/_wsdump.py "wss://mywebsocketserver:3000/message" -t "message"
```

You can end the entrypoint script with the magic line `exec "$@"` to run the `CMD` as the actual main container process.  (Technically, it replaces the current shell script with a command constructed by replaying the command-line arguments; in a Docker context the `CMD` is passed as arguments to the `ENTRYPOINT`.)

```bash
#!/bin/sh
# script.sh

# set up the environment
. /root/.env set

# run the main container command
exec "$@"
```

With this use you can debug the container setup by replacing the command part (only), like

```bash
docker run --rm your-image env
```

to print out its environment.  The alternate command `env` will replace the Dockerfile `CMD` but the `ENTRYPOINT` will remain in place.

Answer (score 0):

You install `script.sh` to the root dir `/`, but your `ENTRYPOINT` is defined to run the relative path `./script.sh`.

Try changing `ENTRYPOINT` to reference the absolute path `/script.sh` instead.

Comment: Even with `ENTRYPOINT` settled to `/script.sh` I have the same strange behaviour, it works only if I `docker run -it --entrypoint=/bin/bash mycontainer` and I launch the `script.sh` manually!

Comment: What happens if you edit your script to use bash rather than dash? i.e. change your script's hashbang to `#!/usr/bin/env bash`.

Comment: Same strange behaviour.